problems with invalid key type and understanding instructions
I am not an experienced programmer. I'm currently teaching myself at home.
I find your instructions for recaptcha2 a bit complicated. I set up for recatcha2. When I am given the keys there are 2 headings: site key and secret key
I am trying to set recaptcha up the simple way but I am confused. The script asks to enter a data site key. It's not indicated so, i tried both. They both  come up with an invalid ker error message.
If I am meant to set up the server side. The instructions are vague. They don't say how to set it up. They just gove the scripts to use. How do I set them up?

please add a link to the instructions you are following or even better also quote their essential parts here

These are the instructions that I am following.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button
and inserting my site key

First: Please add extensions to your question, not as comments.
Second: you linked instructions for reCaptcha v3, but wrote in your question that you are using v2 - there were significant changes between those 2 versions, so please follow the correct instructions.

I trie v2 and 3 neither worked.
Looking atthreads... this has been a long standing issue.
Try making the instructions more user friendly. I wouldn't be so confused.
As I've had no help. I've scrapped this idea and my website. I'll go back to wordpress.
There are alternatives that are easier to understand
